# Error: unknown file system ! Emergency

Tags: grub2, partitioning, filesystem

I don't know what to do, I was taking some space away from my linux partition and I rebooted and this happened I'm completely stuck is there anyway I can change it to boot with windows instead of grub menu stuff or whatever, idk what to do please help!

Comment: Sorry, but I pretty much can't do anything because I can't get past this error thing

Comment: Please edit your question to give us a detailed account of what you were doing in what order. "I was taking some space..." - what program did you use? Did you do that in Windows, Linux or while booted from a LiveCD? What partitions were there? Which one did you move? "I rebooted..." - did you reboot *while resizing the partition*? Or after the process completed? Otherwise all we can provide is guesses.

Answer (score 2):

You likely **moved** the partition slightly when you were resizing it.  If I am correct, you need to fix your `grub` and you should be able to boot normally.

The easiest way to fix your grub is to use **Boot-Repair**

The detailed instructions and more info is [HERE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) but the quick instructions are:

Boot into your LiveCD/USB and type the following into a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update


sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

This will install and then run `boot-repair` in your live environment(nothing will be installed to your hard drive)

When the window pops up click **Recommended Repair**  this will scan your system for any OS's and then install grub with the correct information on the location of your Ubuntu partition and when you exit the live environment and reboot you should be able to load Ubuntu.

[image]

When `boot-repair` runs it will create a file that will be uploaded to paste.ubuntu.com note the url that it gives you and you will be able to link to it to get more help.  More information on this can be found on the link I gave above and well as more detailed instructions and information on advanced options(advanced options are usually not needed in a normal install)

Answer (score 0):

you should create a partition exclusively to boot, so if something wrong happens to your linux partition, the boot partition is untouched!

boot with ubuntu live cd and look at this file (if your partition is accessible): /boot/grub/grub.cfg; there must have a entry there to windows that you may be able to change, but without knowing more details its hard to guess..

what you can do now? you mind reinstalling linux with the cdrom or pendrive? that way it will make available again your windows partition automatically (but you will loose your old linux partition data, unless you resize it without touching the area with data, so you can recover it later in some way).

Ps.: may be you can fix your partitions manually with fdisk using the ubuntu live cd, but requires: "know what you are doing" thing.. I myself havent done that, just a tip to be asked/researched; EDIT: I just remember, there is a flag you can set with fdisk to say the kind of filesystem, set it to ext4, there is a builtin help, do it slowly with care, read it all, list the types and choose the best matching to what you remember it was (probably ext4)